# Clojure: Is it possible to call package protected methods of java?

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am not able to find any documentation (or blogs) regarding this. Is it possible to call package protected methods from clojure? We have a huge java code base and I was thinking if its possible to start developing some clojure libraries around them.

I tried making the namespace same as that of the package in java but the method (static) was not found.

Comment: I don't have a step by step available to answer the quesiton, but for clarification purposes, a namespace in clojure is not a package, it is an Object containing a mapping of var names to values. `(-> (all-ns) first .getMappings class) => clojure.lang.PersistentHashMap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a quick code example:

```
 (def a (ref 0))
 (def klass (class a))
 (def m (.getDeclaredMethod klass "currentVal" (into-array Class [])))
 (.setAccessible m true)
 (.invoke m a (into-array []))
```

You should probably have a look at the [reflect API](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.reflect-api.html)

Although, I would recommend only using the publicly declared fields and methods from your old java code base.